# post between domains and still keep the session

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have two domains A and B. The user uses A and has plenty of data stored in session. Then A make a post to B and supply it's (A's) url. After a while at B it posts back to A using supplied url, but the A's session data is lost. Is it possible to keep the session during these posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response.Cookies["A"] = Request.Cookies["A"] before redirect to B sets "Set-Cookie" http header and solves the problem.